# GitHub: How to test a custom GitHub Action

Tags: java, github-actions, github-pages, javadoc

### Introduction

I'm currently working on a GitHub Action that automatically generates a JavaDoc and publishes it to GitHub Page.
The GitHub project: https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/jib-container-publish.yml

### Problem

This custom GitHub Action does not have any tests inside their GitHub repository.
So I wanted to contribute to this project and add a test.

### Question

Does someone know if it is possible? If it is, how can we do this?